# Why can't I give RDP access to AD users without RDS installed?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, rdp

I have a Windows Server 2012 with three users. I want them to be able to access the server over RDP, however I don't need licensing for my purposes and therefore RDS seems a bit overkill to me. (I am aware of the two-user limit.) I tried simply adding the AD users to the RDP group, but they are still presented with this error message:

[image: RDP error]

How do I give users access to RDP without installing RDS or other roles? This is occurring on a Server 2012 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however I don't need licensing for my purposes

Actually, if I remember rightly, you do. RDP without RDS is only for administrative purposes. If they're not supposed to be administrators of the server then they're not supposed to be connected to it via RDP unless its a properly licenced RDS box.

Other than that, I think the error message (almost) means what it says. Standard users (I'm assuming that's what the users are?) do not have the right to log in to a server interactively and need to be granted this right, along with membership of the RDP users group. Assign the `Allow Logon Locally` right to the users via local group policy on the server.